# Custom rendering of PowerPoint documents in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, powerpoint, rendering

I would like to render uploaded .pptx files directly in my React app, but I would like to have control over the design of the rendered view. Meaning that, instead of relying on the renderer provided by Microsoft, I'd like to have control at least over how the document's toolbar is displayed.

I have tried the [@cyntler/react-doc-viewer](https://github.com/cyntler/react-doc-viewer) package, but it looks like its MS document renderer is just a wrapper for creating an IFrame with an
``` src={``https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/embed.aspx?src=$``{encodeURIComponent( ```
`currentDocument.uri,`
`)}}`

This returns some deeply nested HTML as provided by the MS Office renderer I suppose, and [the rendered view with the default toolbar looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPE39.jpg). Now it might be possible to write some convoluted css / js selectors to manipulate the returned DOM elements and target this toolbar, but I'm looking for a cleaner or more straight-forward solution, since I have no control of what DOM elements will ultimately be returned, so it might break if they change it.

An additional level of difficulty would be to have a level of control where I can render only particular slides, or display the slides of the ppt document in a grid etc, if it's possible to have that level of control over how it's rendered, but as a first step I would be satisfied with customizing the toolbar.